# How does cuhre function work in R?

Tags: r, integration

I am going through my multivariate class notes and it uses cuhre function from R2Cuba package to evaluate probabilty according to rules on variables X & Y. Here's the complete chunk of the code:

```
integrand <- function(z){
    x <- z[1]
    y <- z[2]
    if (0<x & x<1 & 0<y & y<1 & x+y>1)
        f = 6*x*y^2
    else
        f = 0
    return(f)
}

NDIM = 2
NCOMP = 1
int <- cuhre(NDIM, NCOMP, integrand, rel.tol = 1e-3, abs.tol = 1e-12, 
             flags = list(verbose = 2, final = 0))$value

int
```

The result is:

```
> int
[1] 0.8998863
```

I understand that this is the probability based on the rule:

```
0<x<1 & 0<y<1 & x+y>1
```

What I am not able to understand is that integrand has been defined as a function taking z as an argument, so only 1 parameter will be passed. When it is getting called below, it doesn't have any parameters and integration happens twice and probability gets saved in int. I got like 50% of the people but not very 100% clear on how it worked. Somewhere down the line I think we can use Cuhre to calculate marginal probability as well, can we?

Comment: You need to specify where it's from; in this case probably [R2Cuba](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/R2Cuba/html/cuhre.html)?

Comment: Yes it's the cuhre function from R2Cuba package.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, try to see the source of the function to understand how does it work.